# Why does Foreman not output some things until I press Control-C?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, foreman

I just got into rails programming and it looks like there are two programs I can use to run my project locally: rackup and foreman.

One difference I noticed is that foreman will not output some things that I would expect to see and I would see if I ran rackup instead, until I press ctrl+c to close the server. Then all those messages appear, as if they were being hidden.

Is there a reason for this? How can I get foreman to be more verbose?

Comment: is the problem solved for you? Consider marking the correct answer or telling us what's missing.

Answer (score 51):

> If you are not seeing any output from your program, there is a likely chance that it is buffering stdout. Ruby buffers stdout by default.

you can fix this by putting the following code in your development.rb file:

```
$stdout.sync = true
```

http://github.com/ddollar/foreman/wiki/Missing-Output

Comment: Thanks very much! I wonder why this isn't on by default for development environments - feels like a Rails bug.

Comment: But where, exactly, does one put this line inside a Rails app? Inside config/development.rb ?

Comment: @kikito yes - inside your environment rb file. Also, neuromancer should accept this answer.