# Rails server log not outputting immediately

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, webrick, foreman

We use Foreman to start all of our web processes in development.

A while back, I tried to get the ruby-debugger gem working with this setup, but I couldn't, so I abandoned my effort. Along the way, I must have changed some setting or another, and now when I try to look at the server log in real time when I make a request to my local environment, nothing gets printed out. I have to kill foreman in order to see any output from the request.

This is really slowing down my development, as I have to make a request, kill foreman to get information about what went wrong, then start up and try again.

Any ideas how to get my server log to spit out everything as I'm making requests?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It's solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953435/why-does-foreman-not-output-some-things-until-i-press-control-c):

It's as simple as adding a line

```
$stdout.sync = true
```

To your config/environments/development.rb file, then restarting foreman.

Worked for me and makes my life much easier.